# MySQL Installer not launching on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows

I cannot install MySQL on Windows 7, neither the web version, nor the offline version.

Whenever I run the installer all it says is "Please wait while windows configures MySQL installer - comunity" and it closes and nothing happens.

I don't know what happens, if I run the installer on Windows 10 it works perfectly.

Comment: can you make do with MariaDB?

Comment: I need to install MySQL on a client's PC. It must be MySQL.

Comment: is the XAMPP mysql installer working?

Comment: I am not using XAMPP. I have a C# app that uses MySQL as a DataBase.
I need to install MySQL to make it work with the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running CMD as Administrator and ran the installer from there and it worked.